# Apt without ask at night remove some packages

Tags: debian, apt

Today i came to work, and found that some of my perl scripts on work server - do not run. The problem is that  scripts can not find 
some libraries that need to work. However, just yesterday, these libraries have been installed and scripts worked!
It seems that packages have been removed from the system! After reviewing the logs i found this record in /var/log/apt/history.log

Start-Date: 2014-09-26  06:10:33
Remove: libclass-load-perl:amd64 (0.17-1), rrdtool:amd64 (1.4.7-2), libyaml-syck-perl:amd64 (1.20-1),... SKIPED OTHER MOSTLY PERL PACKGES
End-Date: 2014-09-26  06:10:41

BUT!

1 There was no one on the server at this time, and no one would remove these packages.

2.Maybe the server  was hacked, but first obvious signs of hacking is not visible, and secondly very strange that attacker would 
decided to remove these packages

3 All other entries in /var/log/apt/history.log - also have another string CommandLine: - and in this case it absent.

What could have happened?

UPDATE:

A week before (2014-09-19) I have purged munin (but not munin-node!) . Maybe this removed packages is autoremove suggestion for munin ? But
as i know 'autoremove' is not really 'auto' and it needs manual verification before delete something

UPDATE2:

1. unattended-upgrades - not installed
2. /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove

```
APT
{
  NeverAutoRemove
  {
        "^firmware-linux.*";
        "^linux-firmware$";
        "^linux-image.*";
        "^kfreebsd-image.*";
        "^linux-restricted-modules.*";
        "^linux-ubuntu-modules-.*";
        "^gnumach$";
        "^gnumach-image.*";
  };

  Never-MarkAuto-Sections
  {
        "metapackages";
        "restricted/metapackages";
        "universe/metapackages";
        "multiverse/metapackages";
        "oldlibs";
        "restricted/oldlibs";
        "universe/oldlibs";
        "multiverse/oldlibs";
  };
};
```

Comment: You have any configuration management system that synchronizes updates/packages etc between servers?

Comment: No, just default debian apt configuration.

Comment: have you installed unattended-upgrades ? please post the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove

Comment: this smells like ubuntu.

Comment: @eichertc update my post with /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove content. And this is not ubuntu, it is Debian Wheezy

Comment: It is to complicate, we do not know what packages you have there. Munin is using rrdtool and a whole bunch of perl packages and modules. So if you purge munin, packages are removed that where installed together with munin.

Comment: Yes it looks like apt remove dependencies for munin....but i purge munin 7 days ago..

Answer (score 0):

You may have some kind of automatic update solution working, which removes "unused" packages.

When apt finds that there is a package which is not used by other packages, then it is considered "unused" and removed.

If you use `unattended-upgrade` program for automatic updates, try to set `Remove-Unused-Dependencies` to `true`.

Comment: I don't install/configure any automatic update system. But maybe modern debian wheezy distro have some default configuration for this ? Where i can check this ?

Comment: Check if you have `unattended-upgrades` installed. If yes, take a look at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file.